# Use id to find the element to get information and add to array android java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am getting element using

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();
for (View touchable : allTouchables) {
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
// To check if touchable view is button or not
//if( touchable instanceof LinearLayout) {
//System.out.println("LinearLayout "+touchable.toString());
//}
if( touchable instanceof Button) { 
     System.out.println("Button "+touchable.getId());
}
if( touchable instanceof TextView) { 
     TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(touchable.getId());
     System.out.println("TextView "+ question.getText().toString());
     //j.put("key",value);
}
if( touchable instanceof RadioButton) {
     RadioButton value = (RadioButton)findViewById(touchable.getId());
     System.out.println("RadioButton "+value.getText().toString());
}
if( touchable instanceof CheckBox) {
     CheckBox value = (CheckBox)findViewById(touchable.getId());
     System.out.println("CheckBox "+value.getText().toString());
}
j.put("array",myArray);// error1.1
}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference

and error1.1 is:

> Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException

My Question is:

1. How to use `touchable.getId()` to get the id of textview radio button and checkbox? So I can get further information for the said element.
2. Fix exception.

Comment: you can cast touchable directly to view, no need of findViewById, TextView question = (TextView)touchable ;

Comment: @darwin you can add it answer as it answers the question so we can close the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Instead of findViewById(touchable.getId())

Use this

```
if( touchable instanceof TextView) { 
 TextView question = (TextView)touchable;
 System.out.println("TextView "+ question.getText().toString());}
```

2) handle exception by proper try catch method

```
try {
j.put("array",myArray);} catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: how about number 2 problem?by the way i need 2 minutes for accepting answer

Comment: Are you getting complile time error with json exception?

Comment: i have one problem mate textview is not getting text of textvuew but text of radio button. is that correct way of getting text of text ivew?

Comment: The code looks good, you may try debugging an make sure that proper view is getting is if statements.

Comment: what i mean is maybe there is not way getting textview? because radio button and checkbox and edittext is working perfectly i am gettin the text. but for textview nothing is return. let me check again

Comment: what u mean by nothing is return?

Comment: this is how i set the value of text view `TextView tv = new TextView(Questionnaire.this);
tv.setText(obj2.get("questiondisplaynum").toString() +" ."+ obj2.get("question").toString());
tv.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj2.get("questiosysid").toString()));
lll.addView(tv);` i can see it on mobile but in console it echo like `TextView touchable` but it returns radio button value it appears like this on console `TextView touchable Male` Male is radio button text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125662/discussion-between-darwin-and-brownman-revival).

Comment: can you check this question and give some answer opinion : [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039435/create-json-array-java-android/40042426#40042426)