# create json array java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

```
[{
    "surveyid": 1
}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {
    "question": "1"
}, {
    "answer": "john"
}, {
    "question": "2"
}, {
    "answer": "Male"
}, {}, {
    "question": "3"
}, {}, {
    "answer": "Fishes"
}, {
    "answer": "Cats"
}, {
    "answer": "Dogs"
}]
```

This is my out put from making json array from this code :

```js
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray();

try {
  for (View touchable: allTouchables) {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();

    String className = touchable.getClass().getName();
    if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.TextView")) {
      TextView textview = (TextView) touchable;
      String tag = (String) textview.getTag();
      System.out.println("tag  " + tag);
      if (tag.matches("questions")) {
        String questionid = textview.getText().toString().split("[\\(\\)]")[1];
        System.out.println("TextView touchable " + questionid);
        j.put("question", questionid);
      } else if (tag.matches("surveytitle")) {
        int questionid = textview.getId();
        System.out.println("TextView touchable " + questionid);
        j.put("surveyid", questionid);
      }



    } else if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.RadioButton")) {
      RadioButton value = (RadioButton) touchable;
      if (value.isChecked()) {
        System.out.println("RadioButton " + value.getText().toString());
        j.put("answer".toString(), value.getText().toString());
      }
    } else if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.EditText")) {
      EditText value = (EditText) touchable;
      System.out.println("EditText " + value.getText().toString());
      j.put("answer".toString(), value.getText().toString());
    } else if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.CheckBox")) {
      CheckBox value = (CheckBox) touchable;
      if (value.isChecked()) {
        System.out.println("CheckBoxButton " + value.getText().toString());
        j.put("answer", value.getText().toString());
      }
    }
    myArray.put(j);
    System.out.println("myArray j " + j);


  }
  System.out.println("myArray j " + myArray);

} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the format i want is :

```
[{
    "surveyid": 1,
    "question": "1",
    "answer": "john"
}, {
    "surveyid": 1,
    "question": "2",
    "answer": "Male"
}, {
    "surveyid": 1,
    "question": "3",
    "answer": "Fishes"
}, {
    "surveyid": 1,
    "question": "3",
    "answer": "Cats"
}, {
    "surveyid": 1,
    "question": "3",
    "answer": "Dogs"
}]
```

How to make this kind of format for this kind of making of array.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Why you not use gson or jackson?

Comment: Your are getting all views and read some value from them and than add them to your JSONArray, of course output will be like that. When your view class is in the condition of one of the clauses you put some info to a JSONObject and adding it to array. If you want to keep track of answer to the question you must keep track of the question object in the JSONArray and get that question JSONObject and put the answer value to it. Or better first create a java class of question which holds question and answer so you can easyly keep track and modify than convert it to JSONArray

Comment: Take your JSONObject outside of for loop otherwise you will always get only one value in JSONObject as there is `if...else if`.

Comment: @PriyankPatel i put it out and i get the desired format but i only get the last value. for all the elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```js
JSONObject question1 = new JSONObject();
try {
  question1.put("surveyid", "1");
  question1.put("question", "1");
  question1.put("answer", "john");
} catch (JSONException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject question2 = new JSONObject();
try {
  question2.put("surveyid", "5");
  question2.put("question", "6");
  question2.put("answer", "john2");
} catch (JSONException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put(question1);
jsonArray.put(question2);
```

Comment: it is dynamically added so i cant just use this way. if you can see there is a for loop for each touchables

Answer (score 0):

There are many empty object in your output, it means you have add a empty JSONObject into your JSONArray, I think there is some bad logic in your loop block code, for example if nothing condition meets "if" and "else if" it will produce empty object, it needs a "else" clause.

Comment: what do you suggest i put in else ?

Answer (score 0):

To remove **empty objects**, before adding it to array **check its length**. if the length is equal to zero then no need to add current object to array. you can do this by using

```
if(j.length()>0){
 myArray.put(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code sample

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("surveyid", surveyid);
            object.put("question", question);
            object.put("answer", answer);
            jsonArray.put(object);
        }
```